# What does t #define guard(n) asm("#" #n) mean in gcc

Tags: gcc, assembly, macros, inline

What does this macro mean in GCC #define guard(n) asm("#" #n)

Ran into some code that uses this macro as guard(1);... guard(2)... etc.
What does this inline assembly do

asm(#1).. asm(#2)..

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: It does nothing. It just inserts a comment into the assembly output. Presumably it's used to stop the compiler reordering things, as a side effect of `asm`.